# Total all occurrences of individual numbers in database table

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm trying to total all occurrences of each individual number in a database table and return them in an associative array.

As an example, the table may consist of entries of: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 1 4 3 3 4 2

When totaled, this would be 1 = 4, 2 = 3, 3 = 3, 4 = 3.

Ideally this would be returned as an array with keys of 'number' and 'total'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL code that you need is: `SELECT num AS number, COUNT(num) AS occurrences FROM yourtable GROUP BY num`

With the answer you will have at each row the num at the first field and the number of occurences at the second one. Then you can create an array and parte it just looping though the sql respones

Fetch the array would be something like(not tested code, just a guide):

```
$myArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
     $myArray[$row["num"]] = $row["occurrences"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to fetch results and use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$arr = array_count_values($arr);
```

In SQL query you can do the same with `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT number, COUNT(*) as total FROM mytable GROUP BY number
```

The last will return two columns with corresponding data:

```
------------------
| number | total |
------------------
| 1      | 4     |
------------------
| 2      | 3     |
------------------
...
```